# Is there a way to pipe density function to data frame using group_by on multiple columns? I need x and kde probability in the original data frame

Tags: r, kernel-density

I'd like to have KDE probability on a data frame grouped by multiple columns.
Tried:

```
d <- data %>% 
    group_by(type,culture,set) %>%
    do(density(.$obs))
```

> Error in .density(.$obs) : could not find function ".density"

Comment: Could you give some limited, reproducible data?

Answer (score 2):

You should *always* provide minimal reproducible sample data along with your post, so that SO respondents have something to work with. Sample data also often helps us to understand what it is you're trying to do and avoids ambiguities regarding data types.

That aside, a more canonical `tidyverse` approach would be to `nest` data and then `map` `density` to the relevant column. Following is an example based on `mtcars`

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(dens = map(data, ~density(.x$mpg)))
res
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#   gear data               dens
#  <dbl> <list>             <list>
#1     4 <tibble [12 × 10]> <S3: density>
#2     3 <tibble [15 × 10]> <S3: density>
#3     5 <tibble [5 × 10]>  <S3: density>
```

Note how `res$dens` is a `list` of `density` objects.

Comment: it throws error now `+ + + Error in UseMethod("map") : 
  no applicable method for 'map' applied to an object of class "c('vctrs_list_of', 'vctrs_vctr')"`, any idea why?

Comment: @doctorate Not sure what you mean. The code I give above works just fine and results are reproducible. If this is a different issue (involving different data and code) you should post a new question including reproducible & minimal sample data and the necessary code to reproduce the error you're getting. Otherwise we will not be able to help.

Comment: sorry for bringing up this issue, but it turned out that there is a namespace conflict, `map` function was the problem from `mclust` package, the reason for this error, it was fixed by explicitly writing the `purrr:map` function name.